# Magic: The Gathering - Can Charge Counters be put on cards that don't "use" counters themselves?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Some cards allow you to add counters, or move counters, to other cards.  Would you be allowed to do this onto a card that doesn't actually use any counters at all?

For example:
Would [Coretapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpFcv.jpg) be allowed to put a charge counter on itself?  What about putting one on something like [Yotian Soldier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ32u.jpg)?

I understand that a Charge Counter is not a +1/+1 counter, however having them around can be useful for things like [Power Conduit](http://magiccards.info/scans/en/mi/229.jpg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can put Charge Counters anywhere that the ability/spell/whatever allows. For example, Coretapper's ability is limited to "target artifact", so any artifact it can target is fine. This sort of thing is exactly what Power Conduit is designed to take advantage of.

Comment: To clarify: You can put a counter on anything that fulfills the requirements, but they don't necessarily do anything. You can put a charge counter on any artifact, but if neither the game rules nor that artifact's ability (or any other ability) specifies an effect for that specific kind of counter, it simply has no effect.

Comment: Agreed.  Coretapper can't place counters on something with Protection from Artifacts, of course, or a Tatterkite... but any valid target artifact is fair game for building up charge!